# How to display data in Bootstrap Modal when link button click in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to display data in Bootstrap Modal when link button click in ASP.NET. In my code
When i click on link button Modal is opening, but assign values are not displaying. Please tell me how to display modal with assigned values.
Thanks.

.aspx Code:

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="linkButton8" runat="server" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" OnClick="linkButton_Click">CIS Information</asp:LinkButton>

      <div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" align="center">Candidate Information Sheet</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">

                            <table class="table table-bordered" align="center">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Name</td>
                                    <td>
                             <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                    <td>Email</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEnail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

C# Code:

```
 protected void linkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtName.Text = "Name";
            txtEnail.Text = "Mail@gmail.com";
        }
```

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?  I'm not having much luck either...

Answer (score 2):

Remove the data-toggle and update the code behind to be like this:

```
 protected void linkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtName.Text = "Name";
            txtEnail.Text = "Mail@gmail.com";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "modelBox", "$("#myModal").modal('show');", true);
        }
```

It is better though to make the link button has a client side click event that gets the data through ajax, set the textboxs values and use the same `modal('show')` JavaScript function to display the modal box, this will be more efficient and user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding UseSubmitBehavior="false" and using an asp:button instead.

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnModal" runat="server" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" OnClick="linkButton_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false">CIS Information</asp:Button>
```

The UseSubmitBehavior attribute determines whether the Button uses the browsers submit functionality or ASP.NET postback. By default it is set to true.

**Edit**

Due to linkButton not having the "UseSubmitBehavior" property.

Comment: Is your button within a form tag? If not try that.

Comment: LinkButton does not support UseSubmitBehavior: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton(v=vs.110).aspx