# OnClick Event Not Firing Inside LinkButton C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a `LinkButton` that is wired up to an `OnClick` event and an href that fires a pop up modal.

My problem is that the modal window is popping up as expected, but the `OnClick` is not firing, it is not even hitting a break point inside the event.

I will post code below :

```
<asp:LinkButton href="#viewemydevices" data-toggle="modal" ID="ViewMyDevices" runat="server" OnClick="btnViewMyDevices_Click"></asp:LinkButton>

<div class="modal fade" id="viewemydevices" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4>This is a section</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table id="MyDevicesTable" class="table tbody" runat="server" visible="false">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:DataGrid ID="MyDevicesGrid" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped tbody" Visible="false"
                                        AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                                        ForeColor="black"
                                        HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"
                                        HeaderStyle-ForeColor="black"
                                        GridLines="None"
                                        EnableViewState="false"
                                        AllowSorting="True"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



protected void protected void btnViewMyDevices_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //logic goes here
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="ViewDevices" runat="server" OnClick="btnViewMyDevices_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

This updated code fires the on click event, but does not fire the modal...

The end product that is needed is when the link button is clicked it will display the modal and run the click event. The event a query that fills a datagrid in the body of the modal with the result set.

Comment: It looks like you've set the `OnClick` event to `btnViewMyDevices_Click`, but the method is actually called `btnViewATTDevices_Click`. Are you calling the correct method, or is there another called `btnViewMyDevices_Click`?

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake

Comment: It's probably not executing because of redirection using `href`. Try removing the `href` tag for fun and see if it executes.

Comment: I actually tested that, it did not work.. haha

Comment: Have you tried adding the event handler to the `LinkButton`? It would look like this `ViewMyDevices.Click += btnViewMyDevices_Click;`.

Comment: Put that on pageload?

Comment: Best to put it outside of a method to ensure it gets added. Put it at the top of your class where you would put local variables.

Comment: It did not like that eiher

Comment: Your `LinkButton` has no text, are you able to see it? Do you have any other `LinkButton` controls present?

Comment: I added an update to my question

Comment: I found a link that may help [right here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432579/how-to-display-data-in-bootstrap-modal-when-link-button-click-in-asp-net). Sounds like this person had their dialog properly showing.

Comment: It does not look like they ever found a solution...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81908/discussion-between-codeboy-and-testwell).

Comment: Would making this a static webmethod and calling it through AJAX solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing target of modal. Usually

```
data-toggle="modal"
```

used in pare with

```
data-target="#viewemydevices"
```

for greater details please [read this](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp)

**EDIT:**
 this functionality can be achieved by replacing your linkbutton with a regular html button which will display the modal and after that will make an AJAX call to your server-side function. Please see [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709924/call-a-method-in-a-cs-from-javascript/30710317#30710317) for details on placing AJAX call

Comment: How would that fire my on click event?

Comment: I'm answering your "modal not displayed". you stated that server click was resolved

Comment: Perfect. Ok. Let me give it a try when I get to my computer. Stand by

Comment: That displays the modal, but does not fire the click event

Comment: That is correct - to achieve what you intent you will need to replace linkbutton with a html button=>>display your modal and call server-side call using AJAX